# How to convert a .py file to .exe on windows 10

Tags: python

py to .exe, the solutions listed don't work on my PC, I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning what you've tried so far, and you also need to navigate to the directory your file is in. So this would be:

```
pip install pyinstaller 
cd C:\YourDirectory
pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py
```

Comment: so wiil this need to be enterd into powershell or cmd

Comment: this did not work it say pip is not recognised as an internal or excsternal comand, operable program or batch file. thanks anyways

Comment: It sounds like you need to install pip, though this should have been automatic when installing python. But in case it somehow wasn't, i'm gonna suggest installing it manually by running the following command: `py -m ensurepip --upgrade`